# Interacting with VW daemon using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, daemon, vowpalwabbit

I have Vowpal Wabbit (VW) running in daemon mode on my local machine on port 26542. I can verify it is running because it responds to the messages it send to it using `nc`.

```
$ echo ' | a b c' | nc localhost 26542
0.050000 0.050000 0.850000 0.050000
```

I want to write a client in python to do the same thing without calling the system call to `nc`, but rather by using sockets. Here is what I have so far.

```
class VwClient:
    def __init__(self, vwhost, vwport):
        self._host = vwhost
        self._port = vwport
        self._socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self._socket.connect((self._host, self._port))
        print 'Socket connected to', self._host, 'on port', self._port

    def close(self):
        self._socket.shutdown()

    def get(self, message):
        print 'Sent:', self._socket.send(message)
        d = self._socket.recv(1)
        print d
        return d
```

I am invoking it as:

```
client = VwClient('localhost', 26542)
client.get(' | a b c')
```

This is what I see:

```
$ python vw.py
Socket connected to localhost on port 26542
Sent: 8
```

After which it just hangs. What am I missing here? I tried to make the socket non-blocking but then I can't read using `recv()`. I also tried higher buffer sizes in `recv()` (tried 8, 64, 128, 1024) but that didn't work either.

**EDIT**

For anyone else stuck with this issue. The fix was to simply append a newline character to the message. Still, some modifications were needed to the `get` method.

```
def get(self, message):
    self._socket.sendall(message) # better use sendall()
    d = self._socket.recv(1024) # assuming max 1024 are received
    return d
```

This should have been called as `client.get(' | a b c\n') # notice the newline`

Comment: Never mind. Figured out that I had to `self._socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)` after writing to socket. After adding that, this works.

Comment: Although the above works, this is not the ideal solution because I cannot send multiple messages once I shut the writer. So question still open.

Comment: Figured out that I didn't need to SHUT_WR before `recv`. All I had to do was to append a newline to my message. Editing the final solution to reflect that :)

Comment: This would be very slow since you do a context switch plus network round trip on each `vw` example. To significantly increase throughput, you may send a batch of examples --each terminated with a newline-- together in one socket send, then read the response from the socket and iterate on it line by line. Each response/prediction will be on a separate line, just like the inputs were. Also the relative order will be preserved in response vs request.